# Rewrite sql code to work in spark apache sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The code below works in sql server but not in apache spark sql:

```
SELECT t2.*
,CASE 
  WHEN t2.ACode <> t2.ACity AND t2.ACode in (SELECT DISTINCT t6.BCode FROM RiskTable WHERE Risklevel = 'Except') 
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CityRisk
FROM Table1 t2
LEFT JOIN RiskTable t6 ON t2.ACode = t6.BCODE
WHERE t2.message = 4
```

I am getting the error message that

```
AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in Filter/Join and a few commands
```

How can I rewrite the sql code below to work in apache spark sql?

Answer (score 0):

in your sub-query, you use the alias t6 (for RiskTable in the FROM clause), so in this sub-query scope, `t6.BCode` is constant. If you meant to use the `BCode` value from the left-join, you don't need the sub query, and can use

```
 CASE 
      WHEN t2.ACode <> t2.ACity AND t2.ACode = t6.BCode and t6.Risklevel = 'Except'
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CityRisk
```

regardless, you may want to use a different alias for the table queried in the sub query.

If the join condition does not match what you want in your `CASE` clause, you can use another left join to the same sub-query (with only `BCode` in the `SELECT` clause, and use `ACode` and `BCode` for your join condition. The `DISTINCT` is now important to avoid duplications caused by this join. You can then check if the `BCode` returned from this joined query is `NULL`.
something like this:

```
SELECT t2.*
,CASE WHEN t2.ACode <> t2.ACity AND sq.BCode is not null  
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CityRisk
FROM Table1 t2
LEFT JOIN RiskTable t6 ON t2.ACode = t6.BCODE
LEFT JOIN   (
    SELECT DISTINCT rt.BCode FROM RiskTable rt WHERE Risklevel = 'Except'
)  sq ON t2.ACode = sq.BCode -- sq for subquery... 
WHERE t2.message = 4
```